# ssh via putty to a GKE node

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a single node GKE cluster and I'm unable to ssh to the node via putty. 
As per the [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance), I tried uploading ssh key, since it is managed by GKE this option is disabled.

Could you please help me in taking ssh to my GKE node via putty?

Also I couldnt access the kubernetes-dashboard even after running **kubectl proxy** command via gcloud in my browser.

Comment: you can upload SSH key on **Worker** nodes, but not on **Master** node!

Comment: To add on to what Ivan commented. The [Kubernetes dashboard](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/dashboards) for GKE has been deprecated since September 2017. The dashboard can now be viewed from within the GCP console for your cluster.

Comment: @IvanAracki, Thanks for the info. I also tried to  
update ssh file to this instance(worker node), since it is managed by GKE, edit option is disabled.